# Export xlsx file to xml using PowerShell

Tags: excel, xml, powershell

I want to export data that are on an xlsx file ([pets.xlsx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QPP_cVhfp4l5T1I4D5vzydjpDZwlsSn1/view?usp=sharing)) to xml format.

When I use the Excel GUI, I can save the Sheet1 to XML and get the [desired output file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_Mjn08dYocj1dsaAggk8Cfi_oUXk3T6C/view?usp=sharing).

I can also get the desired result by exporting the data through the Developer Tab in Excel GUI.

Now I want to do this in PowerShell.
I used this code that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599987/saving-excel-file-as-xml-with-powershell/68136730?noredirect=1#comment120426394_68136730) :

```
$xlXMLSpreadsheet = 46
$Excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
$WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open("d:\pets.xlsx")
$WorkBook.SaveAs("d:\pets.xml", $xlXMLSpreadsheet)
$Excel.Quit()
```

The problem is that the generated xml file is not the expected result.

Thanks in advance

Amine

Note : I've also posted the problem [here](https://forums.powershell.org/t/export-xlsx-file-to-xml/16927) to maximize my chances to solve the problem.

Comment: In what way is the generated file not what you expect?

Comment: In [that](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XzdpfEwaReiase6DFV0IN9N3m8pCC2fW/view?usp=sharing) way

Comment: The list of supported formats is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat). The only plausible candidate is `xlOpenXMLWorkbook`, but I'm not sure that's it.

Comment: I don't think `$xlXMLSpreadsheet = 46` corresponds to the XML file format you need; rather, it corresponds to an [**XML Spreadsheet**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.XlFileFormat) file format, which is why you are not getting the output you desire. You are probably going to have to use an approach similar to [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63670421/powershell-script-to-copy-specific-text-from-excel-create-xml-files).

Answer (score 0):

After many searches and tries, I've written this, and it works :

```
$Excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
$WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open("d:\pets.xlsx")
$WorkBook.XmlMaps("pets_Mappage").Export("d:\pets.xml")
$Excel.Quit()
```